# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found):How to Handle error if iframe src gives 404 Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, axios, onerror

I have been digging deep regarding i-frames. I am stuked at point i can't get error code when i-frame failed to load something. and Every time i am getting only error, without any access of it,
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Can Anybody tell me how can i get an proper error object and use it to  display custom message?

```
<iframe
  className="responsive-div"
  id="iframe-test"
  onLoad={(e) => {
    console.log("first".e);
  }}
   src={URL}
>
```

Comment: You mean, you want to get the actual HTTP status code of the response? I don't think you can get the from the load event (or the error event either, for that matter.) You could try and request the URL using fetch - but then it won't work for resources that aren't CORS-enabled. Plus, the request itself might well succeed - but the browser might be instructed not to display the resource in foreign frames, so you would then need to check for an `X-Frame-Options` header, resp. check the CSP for a `frame-ancestors` directive, as well ...